# How to stop airflow running dags (at unscheduled times) automatically when initially turned on?

Tags: airflow

How to stop airflow running dags (at unscheduled times) automatically when initially turned on?

My dags look like...

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'rvillanueva',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 10, 13),
    'email': ['me@co.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    # 'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'max_active_runs': 3,
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('mydag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="10 22 * * *")
...
```

I had thought that having `depends_on_past=False` or `catchup=False` would be enough to stop this, but dags are still running once right when they are turned on in the webserver UI (causing them end up overlapping runs on their actual scheduled times in some cases).

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Potentially due to bug documented here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3369. Will continue debugging to determine more.

Comment: Possible workaround for now: "If you set the start date = to the most recent interval it will only schedule 1 DAG run. for example, if deploying your dag on 11/19 and it should run daily. Set your start_date to 11/18. It will not schedule the 11/17 DAG run in this scenario". See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3369?focusedCommentId=16692131&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16692131